How do I allow the user to change the URL in the address bar for a window opened with window.opn?
I want to open a window (window.open) and allow the user to change the URL in he Address Bar.
I've looked at other questions about this but I've not found a solution.
One answer I found to another question was to open the window in a new window/tab using "_blank" as the second parameter to the window.open function. The person said that would cause the window to not be a popup - whatever that means.
That only works if you pass only the fist two parameters. If you specify something in the third parameter, such as setting the window size, the URL in the address bar cannot be changed by the user.
Here's code that works - you can type whatever  you want into the address bar - but I cannot specify the third parameter (no comments on crudity of code example, please - it is dirt simple but it accomplishes the objectives)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<script>
function openwind() {
    open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", "status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menu=yes,location=yes,height=600px, width=800px,toolbar,directories=yes");
}   
</script>
</head><input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick='openwind()' />
<body>
<input name="url" type="text">// not used
</body>
</html>

The following code does not work. The window is opened with all the setting specified but you cannot type in the address bar. No keystrokes will cause a change the contents of the address bar.
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<script>
function openwind() {
    open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", "status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menu=yes,location=yes,height=600px, width=800px,toolbar,directories=yes");
}   
</script>
</head><input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick='openwind()' />

<body>
<input name="url" type="text">

</body>

</html>

Does anyone have any thoughts on the matter?
Bob

The functionality you desire is intentionally restricted because it is a security risk.

Joseph, how so is it a security risk.

And, why does it work if I don't specify more than two parameters for the .open function?

Phishing scams, for one. You could open phishingbank.com then change the URL to legitbank.com. The number of parameters doesn't matter, just if it's using parameters that will cause the URL to open in a new window rather than a new tab, like width and height.

My audgionx was not a out programmically chning th URL. I t  was hoy to llow a usr to chnge thhe  address in tyh4 dddrr4es box.
